# Django and JSON - additional attributes

Tags: jquery, django, json

I don't understand why code like this give "has_children" attribute to every item object:

```
items = Items.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(parent=None)
for i in items:
    if i.get_children():
        i.has_children = True
    else:
        i.has_children = False
return render_to_response('items_base.html', {'items': items}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But code like this, don't do the trick, even if it don't raise any errors:

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['ContentType'] = "text/javascript"
try:
    items = Items.objects.get(id=id).get_children()    
    for i in items:
        if i.get_children():
            i.has_children = True
        else:
            i.has_children = False                
    response.write(serializers.serialize("json", items))
    return response
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse(u"There is no page like this")
```

Has someone has any suggestions of what is wrong with secuond code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django serialization is excluding any attributes which were not actually defined as model fields.

You have some options:

- Convert the Item objects into dictionaries of `{fieldname: value}` and use the `json` library to serialize them (or create a custom [JSONEncoder](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)).
- Use this ['Full Serializer'](http://wadofstuff.blogspot.com/2009/02/django-full-serializers-part-i.html) code to serialize your extra fields.

Comment: Yep. Working fine. I chose secound option. Thanks.